# Knockout + mvc 3 + Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, knockout.js

In the controller I would like to be able to get to the client validation rules of the model. I've attached some attributes using data annotations and would like to be able to pass something back to the client via the ajax call so I can then build the jquery validate options automatically.

Normally this is done for free with the unobtrusive stuff, but I'm trying to leverage knockout binding, while still not having to replicate the validation rules on both the server and client.

Without using reflection on the model server side I'm a little unsure on how to achieve this.

Comment: Have you found an acceptable solution for this?  If so, please answer your own question here.

Comment: Not at the moment, moved onto another project but will be heading back.

Comment: See that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878639/upshot-mvc-4-handling-of-date-knockout-bindings/9890429#9890429

Comment: [see it](http://mitchelltrent.com/post/2011/06/19/Creating-Custom-Data-Annotations-that-emit-Unobtrusive-Validation-Attributes.aspx)

Answer (score 26):

In my [Mvc Controls Toolkit](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/) I developed Helpers based on the knockout library. These helpers not only help in writing the knockout code, but enhance the knockout library with Unobtrusive validation and globalization. Moreover, the binding mechanism is enhanced to include complex controls such as a DatetimePicker, and other "complex" (made by different html parts) controls.

Finally, knockout templates can be defined through Razor helpers.

See the documentation [here](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Client%20Blocks), [here](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Client%20Block%20complete%20example), [here](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ClientBlockRepeater) and [here](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Client-Side%20Templates). I also have some tutorials that show how to implement advanced features with my helpers:

[Low BandWidth Transfers with The Client Side Templates of the Mvc Controls Toolkit](http://www.dotnet-programming.com/post/2011/10/28/Low-BandWidth-Transfers-with-Client-Side-Templates-of-the-Mvc-Controls-Toolkit.aspx)

[Handling Big Amounts of Data with Client-Side Templates](http://www.dotnet-programming.com/post/2011/10/29/Handling-Big-Amounts-of-Data-with-Client-Side-Templates.aspx)

[Handling Big Amounts of Data with Client-Side Templates 2](http://www.dotnet-programming.com/post/2011/10/29/Handling-Big-Amounts-of-Data-with-Client-Side-Templates-2.aspx)

Comment: This is great, but I'm using FluentValidation for my validation, which updates ModelState object. When a view is rendered the errors from ModelState, which were generated by FluentValidation framework, are applied to each input appropriately. Does MVC Controls Toolkit looks at ModelState to figure out which inputs need to be highlighted?

Comment: Server Side errors are taken from the model state, so they works with whatever technolgy that use the modelstate...also if you add errors manually to the Modelstate.

Comment: I would hate triple effort for validation. Validate Domain Models, Validate View Models, now another library .. its kind of duplication. Should be **ONE** validation, not 3.

Comment: Please explain???? The Purpose Of This library Is Just avoiding duplivation Of Validation Rules. In fact It reuses data Annotations Defined On The Server Side to Perform validation On The Client Viemodel....

Answer (score 1):

Depeneding on what you exactly need to do, [Breeze js](http://learn.breezejs.com/) can be the best solution. particularly, if you're using EF, you can replicate most of the functionality of the server EF's `DbContext` on the client side, including, of course, the validation, but also change tracking, `.saveChanges`, a simple syntax that resembles LINQ queries, caching, serializing and deserializing to allow working offline, and many other things.

The basic steps to work with Breeze js are:

- create an EF model in the server
- add a NuGet Package on the server to create Web API Services that expose the model to the client side. This is done with a surpringly low number of C# code. One of the things that this does is exposing the metadata: definition of objects, relations, and extra information, like data annotations validation info
- add a js Nuget Package for the client side which will be used to replicate the EF behavior on the client side.

Of course, not all of the functionality on the server will be replicated on the client, but you can do a lot of things:

- create new entities on the client side
- make queries on the client side, which will be executed on the server and returned to the client
- modify entities on the client: create, modify, delete...
- create relations on the client side: for example create new chlid entities in a parent object
- call `saveChanges` on the client side, which will transfer all the tracked changes to the server so that the backend is updated
- of course, while you do this, you'll get automatic client validation, and also additional server validation whenever you call `.saveChanges`

Finally, you can extend and modify the server code to include some business logic, so that you can do much more than simply exposing the EF model to the client.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a task. You want to be able to convert your C# code into Javascript with respective data type conversions etc. You'll be better off writing down two separate sets of validation at server and client side both. It would be a lot more easier to maintain that than to write your own conversion framework all by yourself and maintaining it

Comment: I didn't think it would be easy :-s

Comment: There could be a small set of standard validation types (eg. required, regex, etc) that can generate JS on the fly; only for custom validators would you have to implement on both client and server.

Answer (score 0):

On the model use attributes validation that you like:

```
 public class ModelWithValidation
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

In mvc forms

```
@using( Html.BeginForm())
{    
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new {data_bind = "value: name"})
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
}
```

In jQuery test if form is valid onSubmit or in knockout save function call the next code to validate input. You must include jQuery.unobtrusive* and jQuery.validate* libraries. Don't forget to validate input on server side also!

```
var form = $("form");
form.removeData('validator');
form.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

$("form").valid() //true false
```